# Excel Formula to extract previous word (towards left) from a specific position

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have multiple records as below in an excel file say Col A:

- Infogain India (P) Ltd. 3-6 yrs Noida
- ROBOSPECIES TECHNOLOGIES PVT LTD 0-2 yrs New Delhi
- Red Lemon 0-3 yrs Noida(Sector-7 Noida)

Within the data there is a range of years mentioned e.g. 3-6 yrs in the first list item.

I want to extract the data 3-6, 0-2, 0-3 etc from above 3 list items. I understand a search for " yrs " in all the strings will give me the end position. However, I am unable to determine how to find the starting position of the Number of years.

I require the excel formula which will give me the year range.
I do not want to use any VBA for the solution.

Comment: can there be numbers elsewhere in the string? Is it always space number(s) -number space yrs?

Comment: Yes, there can be numbers or dash in the string anywhere. The only fixed string is " yrs ". So we have to work from this specific string

Comment: with Office 365 use this array formula: `=CONCAT(IF(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$50)-1)*999+1,999))="yrs",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$50)-2)*999+1,999)),""))` it does not matter the size of the "word" preceding `yrs`.

Comment: @ScottCraner the ROW($1:$50) in your formula is generating a circular reference.

Comment: It would only be circular if the cell reference `A1` in the formula is referring to itself.  There are two and both need to point to the actual cell with the text.  The rows is just a counter and will not cause the circular reference but the one you accepted is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no spaces between numbers then you can use following formula.

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A3," yrs",REPT(" ",99)),99))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

Comment: Works like a charm - short & crisp. It also takes into account the double digit years like 12-15 yrs etc. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @SagnikPal Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following though pretty sure it can be condensed. I have attempted to handle additional white space potentially being present and also the years being multi digit in length e.g. 12-15. Incorporates a method by [Raystafarian](https://superuser.com/questions/740476/find-last-instance-of-a-character-in-string-and-keep-anything-that-comes-before) to find a last occurence of a character.

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND("yrs",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),1)-1)),LEN(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND("yrs",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),1)-1)))-LOOKUP(9.9999999999E+307,FIND(" ",TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND("yrs",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),1)-1)),ROW($1:$1024))))
```

Comment: @pnuts: I was worried about the length of the years being more than 1 digit and potentially additional whitespace. That said, i'm pretty sure i have overcomplicated things.

Comment: @pnuts true true true

Comment: Thanks QHarr for your help. The formula works great & also takes into account double digit years like 12-17 yrs. Only point where I am inclined to use the formula from redij is that the formula is very crisp from redij.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(A1, FIND(" yrs", A1), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), 4))
```

Comment: That code looks good but could you please update your answer to explain what you are doing and how you arrive to your respond

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. This formula works fine if the number of years are only single digit like 2-3 yrs. (as we are taking 4 characters from right where yrs is found). However, the years can be 12-17 yrs etc as well. So the count of characters has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below formula

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ","|",LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ",""))-1),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ","|",LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ",""))-1))-SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ","|",LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("yrs",A1)-1)," ",""))-1))))
```

Comment: Thanks Karthick for your help. The formula works great & also takes into account double digit years like 12-17 yrs. Only point where I am inclined to use the formula from redij is that the formula is very crisp from redij.